# Get the value of a column when column name is in a variable

Tags: r

How could I get the value of a column based on another column which contain the name of it?

Exemple:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(variable = c("var1", "var2", "var1", "var3")
             , var1 = rnorm(4)
             , var2 = rnorm(4)
             , var3 = rnorm(4))

  variable       var1       var2       var3
1     var1 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814
2     var2  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884
3     var1 -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812
4     var3  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432
```

## output:

```
c(-0.6264538, -0.8204684, -0.8356286, 0.3898432)
```

Comment: `df[as.character(df$variable)][cbind(seq_along(df$variable), seq_along(df$variable))]`

Comment: does it matter the order of the values?

Comment: @Joanna How is this any different than Kelli-Jean's answer already posted?

Comment: Oh, thanks for reminding. My fault, I think we are doing same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be accomplished with a simple `for()` loop and the extract operator `[`.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(variable = c("var1", "var2", "var1", "var3")
                 , var1 = rnorm(4)
                 , var2 = rnorm(4)
                 , var3 = rnorm(4),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
aResult <- NULL
# use extract operator with indexed reference to variable column
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) aResult[i] <- df[i,df[i,"variable"]]
aResult
```

...and the output:

```
> aResult
[1] -0.6264538 -0.8204684 -0.8356286  0.3898432
>
```

Similarly, we could use `sapply()` to replace the `for()` loop.

aResult <- sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x,y){
                     df[x,df[x,"variable"]]
              },y=df)

...and the output:

```
> aResult2 <- sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x,y){
+                 df[x,df[x,"variable"]]
+      },y=df)
> aResult2
[1] -0.6264538 -0.8204684 -0.8356286  0.3898432
>
```

### Benchmarking the alternatives

Given that there are at least three different ways to solve this problem (i.e use of the `diag()` function noted in the OP comments and another answer), it's worthwhile to ask whether one approach is significantly faster than the others. We can answer this question with the `microbenchmark` package.

To make R expend more time on the problem, we'll create a data frame with 500 columns and 10,000 rows.

```
rowCount <- 10000
varCount <- 500
variable <- paste0(rep("X",rowCount),rep(1:varCount,rowCount / varCount))

df <- cbind(variable,
            data.frame(matrix(runif(rowCount * 
                       varCount),nrow=rowCount,ncol=varCount)),
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Next, we'll use the `microbenchmark` package to compare the three approaches.

```
library(microbenchmark)

myForLoop <- function(){
     for(i in 1:nrow(df)) aResult[i] <- df[i,df[i,"variable"]]
}

myDiag <- function(){
     diag(as.matrix(df[df$variable]))
}
mySapply <- function() {
     sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x,y){
          df[x,df[x,"variable"]]
         },y=df)
}
funcList <- list(myForLoop=myForLoop,myDiag=myDiag,mySapply=mySapply)

microbenchmark(list=funcList,unit="ns",times=1000L)
```

When we run the benchmark 1,000 times on each approach we obtain the following results, illustrating that the three approaches have very similar performance characteristics. The fastest approach on average is less than 1 ns faster than the slowest average. Given that there are other processes running on the computer that may contribute to variability in the benchmark, we conclude that there are no meaningful differences in the average response times.

```
> theModel <- microbenchmark(list=funcList,unit="ns",times=1000L)
> autoplot(theModel)
> print(theModel)
Unit: nanoseconds
      expr min lq  mean median uq max neval cld
 myForLoop   2  7 6.981      7  7 361  1000   a
    myDiag   2  7 7.160      7  8 260  1000   a
  mySapply   2  7 6.613      7  7  93  1000   a
>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
# Make sure `df$variable` is not a factor
df$variable = as.character(df$variable)

# Subset and convert to matrix in order to take diagonal entries:
diag(as.matrix(df[df$variable]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Step one: split df into a list by each row

```
df <- data.frame(variable = c("var1", "var2", "var1", "var3")
             , var1 = rnorm(4)
             , var2 = rnorm(4)
             , var3 = rnorm(4))

xy.list <- split(df, seq(nrow(df)))
```

Step two: minimal function to select each column of each element that matches the Variable name

```
 sel<-function(x){x[x$variable]}
```

Step three: Apply this function to each element using Map()

```
  result<-map(xy.list,sel )
  unlist( flatten(result)  )
```

Output:

```
 > unlist( flatten(result)  )
  var1       var2       var1       var3 
 -0.6264538 -0.8204684 -0.8356286  0.3898432
```